# Form Encode with PHP rawurlencode and Slashes

Tags: php, html, forms, get, encode

I have a self-submitting selectbox which takes the current $_GET variable in the url in order to direct the user to the same page. It's currently working well but it looks ugly in the address bar.

The link goes from:

`https://website.com/?x=directory/webpage`

to

`https://website.com/?x=directory%2Fwebpage&test=0`

Is it possible to retain the "/" instead of using "%2F" once the page loads?

**Example code:**

```
<form method="get" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type='hidden' name='x' value='<?php=rawurldecode($_GET['x']);?>'>
<select id='test1' name='test1' onchange='this.form.submit()'>
<option selected disabled>Select</option>
<option value="1">test</option>
</select>
<noscript><input type='submit' value='Submit'></noscript>
</form>
```

Comment: Since you aren't sending a POST, why not just send a redirect?

Comment: I'm not sure if this would be applicable or how to implement this. My goal here is to take the selection value from the drop-down and attach it to the current url. So if I selected value 2, the page would reload with `test=2` at the end.